# anyone got mapdeck working with OSGB vector tiles?

Tags: mapdeck

Trying to stretch my understanding of how mapdeck can plot maps and the new (new to me) Ordnance Survey Vector Tile API that can display 3D buildings
See
https://labs.os.uk/public/os-data-hub-examples/os-vector-tile-api/vts-example-3d-buildings

Has anyone any advice about how to reference the labs.os.uk data as a layer in mapdeck?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is not possible to set a `transformRequest` function when using Mapbox via  Mapdeck.

But you can probably do it by downloading the tile json from `https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts&key=your_os_api_key&srs=3857`

Edit by appending `&srs=3857` to the "tiles" url.

Save the edited tile json to your server.

Then download a copy of the 3d style json from https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-Vector-Tile-API-Stylesheets/blob/master/OS_VTS_3857_3D.json

Edit by appending `&key=your_os_api_key` to the "sprite" and "glyphs" urls, and edit the "sources" "url" entry to point the tile json on your server.

Save the edited style json to your server.

Hopefully Mapdeck can then be used with `style =` parameter set to the url of the style json on your server.